# Align view weight dynamically - Android

Tags: android-layout, android

Use Case:

I have a Horizontal view H, which contains 5 buttons(A,B,C,D & E); all taking equal space in H. Now depending on certain business logic each of these buttons may or may not be visible. In case a button is invisible, rest of the buttons should align themselves equally.

Now the problem is if I give specific weights to each of these buttons then I have to write 2^5 if-else cases to assign individual weights to buttons. Isn't there a way in Android that all these buttons align them self taking equal space on their own. Precisely the idea is to write just 5 cases where I make a button visible or invisible and rest view align itself on its own. I can not use wrap content as these buttons contain text of different length and I want the buttons to take equal space and not the text.

Is there a way of doing this? I'll highly appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign all your buttons equal weight (e.g. 1), but don't assign weight sum to the container. Now, when you need to hide a button, set its visibility to `GONE`, and other buttons will be resized equally to take available space.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for such a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now if you set the third button visible the other two buttos will resize to show 3 buttons on screen. And the same view in horizontal layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!